# Managing Google Sheets API Refresh Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

I am using **Google Sheets** for my website to store certain order information. The problem I'm dealing with is that the `access_token` expires within about *an hour* and the `refresh_token` lasts me *a couple of days* at most before it expires.

Once my `refresh_token` expires I have to:

1. Physically log into Google with my app URL
2. Accept Scopes and copy the auth code
3. Make a code grant request to get issued a new refresh token

The above process is manual, tedious and unbearable after a month.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Although I cannot understand your actual situation and your script, I proposed 2 workarounds as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I'm dealing with is that the access_token expires within about an hour and the refresh_token lasts me a couple of days at most before it expires.

Refresh tokens only last seven days if your application is still in testing. Go to Google cloud console and set it to production.  Your refresh token will then stop expiring.

[image]

> I am using Google Sheets for my website to store certain order information.

If you are only using a sheet that you the developer control.  This meaning that you are not accessing sheets owned by your users on their own google drive accounts.   Then you should consider using a Service account.   [Should you be using a Google service account](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UTTTtwb7x7g&list=PLws6LF6K-IU-zzbgwzyHh9IQ1zCpBwwnf)

Comment: DalmTo, thank you very much for your answer. I will now try to test it out before accepting it as the answer. I am relieved by you giving me not one but two different options.

Comment: I created a service account and gave permissions to the sheet I used and voila, it worked. The credentials seem very static.. I might need to dig into the process a bit more but the private keys are included in the token.json. Thank you very much!

Comment: As I probably mentioned in the video.  If at all possible one should use a service account the authorization method is so much easer.

Comment: Indeed, now I can sign my own tokens and specify my own expirations on my  access_tokens. I'm so glad you found my question, nice video I felt like a textbook case.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I cannot understand your actual situation and your script, how about the following pattens?

#### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the service account is used. When the service account is used, the access token can be retrieved without authorizing the scopes using the browser. You can use Sheets API using the access token.

#### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used. When Web Apps created by Google Apps Script is used, the Web Apps is used without the authorization process because when Web Apps is deployed, the authorization process is done. And, in this case, the Spreadsheet service can be used. So it is not required to use Sheets API. And, I think that Web Apps can be used as the wrapper API for Sheets API you are using. When you use this pattern, you can use Web Apps by an HTTP request.

#### References:

- [Service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts?hl=en)
- [Create a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount)
- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)